# Querying array of nested documents for more than one value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a mongodb collection `Student` as shown:

```
[{
    "name" : "John",
    "age" : 19,
    "hobbies" : [
        {
            "hobbyName" : "Sleeping",
            "proficiency": "Expert"
        }, 
        {
            "hobbyName" : "Coding",
            "proficiency": "Beginner"
        },
        {
            "hobbyName": "Googling",
            "proficiency": "Expert"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Michael",
    "age" : 22,
    "hobbies" : [
        {
            "hobbyName" : "Eating",
            "proficiency": "Expert"
        }
    ]
}]
```

A student can have many hobbies. For querying with a single hobby, I can simply use `Student.find({hobbies.hobbyName: "Coding"})`. But what if I want to find all students with one or more hobbies. Say I want to find all students who have Coding and Sleeping as their hobbies. The query should return all students who have both the hobbies. They may or may not have any other hobby. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$all`.

```
db.Student.find({
  "hobbies.hobbyName": {
    "$all": [
      "Coding",
      "Sleeping"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SfTWSUreuWc)

Comment: I thought that $all worked only for finding items in arrays. It works for objects as well. Thanks!